# which event occurs on a parent form after closing its modal child form in WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms

My Programme uses a modal child form. After closing it I'd like to refresh some controls reading their values in a XML file. Which WinForms event should I use in order to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about immediately following the ShowDialog?

```
fooForm modal = new fooForm();
modal.ShowDialog();
//your code to refresh some controls here <<-----------------------<<<<<<
```

Comment: Thanks! The simplest way was not obvious to me : )